# Tables Not Aligning/Can't fix resolution

Tags: html, css, css-tables, screen-resolution

This is the first site I've made, and I'm just struggling with a few things. Let me explain the issues.

1. I have a screen with a resolution of 1366 X 768, which I have designed on, and it looks great there. However, when I move it over to my larger screen(2560X1080), several elements shift around and it looses the design that I intended. How do I set a max resolution? I've tried, but nothing seems to work.
2. I have a table set up half way down my page, and I can NOT get them to align horizontally. I probably just have too much code, and it's made a mess somehow.

Help appreciated.

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 70%;
  height: 2000px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  max-width: 900px;
}

div#wrapper {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #777;
}

.top {
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: ;
  height: 200px;
}

h1 {
  color: #cc4f41;
  text-decoration: ;
}

div {
  display: block;
  height: 225px;
}

.headertext {
  font-size: 25px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.japanname {
  margin-left: 600px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.rank {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 115px;
  margin-left: 550px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
}

.logoimage {
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 2%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: ;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.text {
  color: #cc4f41;
  font-family: permanent marker;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}


/* basic info box*/

.info {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 900px;
  padding-top: 17%;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-image: ;
}

.whois {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-left: 18%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  color: #ebd234;
  position: absolute;
  font-kerning: auto;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-family: permanent marker;
}

.infopara {
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 50%;
  margin-top: 170px;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.fullbody {
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 33%;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.hw {
  margin-top: 120px;
  margin-left: 470px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px #cc4f41 dotted;
  border-radius: 40%;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.infotable {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 350px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 300px;
}

.infotable th {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #cc4f41;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #cc4f41;
}


/*abilities*/

.abilities {
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.head2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-top: 33px;
  height: 50px;
}

.glove {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 10%;
}

.abhead {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 75px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: oblique;
}

.twocolumn {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 400px;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-left: 25px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 30%;
}

.dot2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
  opacity: 50%;
}


/*disciples*/

.disciple {
  background-color: black;
  height: 500px;
}

.genos {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 5%;
  max-width: 35%;
}

.head3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 80%;
  padding-top: 3%;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.h3 {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  font-family: permanent marker;
}

.discp {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 37%;
  padding-top: 36%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Saitama</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Permanent+Marker&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- top box -->


  <div class="top">

    <div class="container">
      <img src="img/closeupface.png" style="float:left" class="logoimage">

      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">Just a hero for fun</div>
      </div>


      <div class="headertext" style="float:right">
        <h1>Saitama</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="japanname">サイタマ</div>
      <div class="rank">B-Class: Rank 7</div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- basic info box -->

  <div class="info">
    <div class="whois">WHO IS
      <BR> HE?</div>
    <div class="infopara" align="center">The main protagonist of the series and the titular One-Punch Man and the most powerful being to exist in the series. Saitama faces a self-imposed existential crisis, as he is now too powerful to gain any thrill from battle.</div>
    <table class="infotable">
      <tr>
        <th>AGE</th>
        <th>GENDER</th>
        <th>JOB</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>Hero</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="hw" style="float:right">175cm<br>70kg</div>
    <img src="img/fullbody.png" style="float:right " class="fullbody">
  </div>

  <br><br><br>

  <!-- abilities -->

  <div class="abilities">
    <img src="img/glove-01.png" class="glove">
    <div class="head2">ABILITIES</div>
    <!-- color for background : #ebd234 -->
    <div class="twocolumn" style="background-color: #ebd234">

      <div class="abhead">Unparalleled Strength</div><br><br><br>

      <div class="abhead">Enhanced Leap</div><br><br><br>

      <div class="abhead">Shockwave Generation</div><br><br><br>

      <div class="abhead">Air Manipulation</div><br><br><br>

      <div class="abhead">Non-physical interaction</div><br><br><br>

      <div class="abhead">Unparalleled Speed & Reflexes</div><br><br><br>

      <div class="abhead">Immeasurable Dexterity</div>
    </div>
    <div class="twocolumn" style="background-color: #cc4f41">

      <div class="abhead">Immeasurable Agility</div><br><br><br>

      <div class="abhead">Immense Stamina</div><br><br><br>
      <img src="img/face-01.png" class="dot2">
      <div class="abhead">Invulnerability</div><br><br><br>

      <div class="abhead">Enhanced Lung Capacity</div><br><br><br>

      <div class="abhead">Vacuum Adaptation</div><br><br><br>

      <div class="abhead">Temperature Immunity</div><br><br><br>

      <div class="abhead">Pain Suppression</div><br><br><br>

    </div>

  </div>
  <br><br>

  <!-- disciples -->

  <div class="disciple">
    <div class="head3">DISCIPLES</div>
    <img src="img/genos.png" class="genos">
    <div class="h3">GENOS</div>
    <div class="discp"> The deuteragonist of One-Punch Man. He is a 19-year-old cyborg and the disciple of Saitama. He is always aiming to become more powerful and fights for justice. Under the Hero Association, he is given the name Demon Cyborg and is currently S-Class
      Rank 14.</div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You wont ever have something responsive based on your code. I just take the class `.japanname` you have `position: absolute + margin-left in px` so for the snippet, you wont ever feet, so a smart phone... I think you need to take the whole code back... `body` setting are in general  looking like `width: 100vw; overflow-x: hidden;`. And then you set a custom container

Comment: you have many fundemantal issues here. Lets start with `body { width: 70%}`... that complete BS! Dont give the body a width! If you want to have the conetent of the website only to use 70% of the space, give the body a padding left and right of 15%. Same with max-width. Then you have structure problems like having a `body {max-width: 900px}` and then elemnts which a childs to the body with a max-width of 1000px. YOu can not make child larger then the parent!

Answer (score 0):

As @MaxiGui suggest always try to use relative units like rem,em,vh,vw if you want to create a responsive website. use px only in the case where you are certain that the height and width is not going to change irrespective of the screen dimension.
You have used fixed value for some margin, height and width try to remove them and then it will work

Comment: its not an anwser to the question which will not fix anythign as there to many fundemental flaws. For that you got a comment option.